# How do I use WorksheetFunction.Text to convert a date from M/D/YY to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I have a date in cell B7 in my worksheet that is formated as 9/1/2019, I want to convert it to a text string in the format YYYY-MM-DD or 2019-09-01.
I tried using WorksheetFunction.Text and searched the web for examples, but my code just generated a "True" result instead of a reformatted date.

This code did not work:

```
Dim FormattingValue As String
Dim FormattingResult As String

FormattingValue = WS1.Range("B7").Select

FormattingResult = WorksheetFunction.Text(FormattingValue, "YYYY-MM-DD")

Debug.Print FormattingResult
```

The Debug.Print returns the value "True" and not a date in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
The code below does work thanks to the contributors:  

Dim FormattingResult As String 

FormattingResult = Format(WS1.Range("B7").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")  

Debug.Print FormattingResult  

This successfully converted 11/5/19 to 2019-11-05
```

Comment: "Dim FormattingValue As String" is incorrect, converting it to a text will lose the actual value. It needs to be a Date / Variant. Also as others answered below, instead of .Select use .Value

Comment: Thank you. I'm just starting with VBA and I really appreciate the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select` doesn't return a value, so this doesn't work as you expect:

> ```
> FormattingValue = WS1.Range("B7").Select
> ```

In VBA you use can `Format()`, and there's no need to select anything:

```
Debug.Print Format(WS1.Range("B7").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Comment: Based on your suggestion I changed the code (see below) and it works perfectly. Thanks so much!
   

Dim FormattingResult As String
    
FormattingResult = Format(WS1.Range("B7").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    
Debug.Print Updated_YYYY_MM_DD

Comment: How do you add code to the comments and get it to look nice and neat on this page?  I entered the comment above with spaces and each sentence on a separate row but when I saved the comment it all got mushed into one long string.

Comment: You can’t do that in a comment

Comment: You can always edit your question to add additional code.